# Как загрузить изображение через JS на хостинг изображений?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот готовый рабочий код, но как указать файл с компьютера а не с сервера `var imgUrl = "http://i.imgur.com/l5OqYoZ.jpg";`?

```
var clientId = "6b72b846602****";
var imgUrl = "http://i.imgur.com/l5OqYoZ.jpg";

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {image: imgUrl},
    success: showMe,
    error: showMe,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
    }
});

function showMe(data) {
    $("body").append(JSON.stringify(data));
    if(data.success == true) {
        $("body").append("<img src='"+data.data.link+"'/>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто заменить строку с ссылкой на файл из `input[type='file']`.
А так же указать параметр `type` - `file`.

Параметр `image` может быть бинарным файлом, `base64`-закодированными данными или ссылка на изображение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Подробнее в документации](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image).

Comment: Вот картинка в Base64, но не работает. Если использывать url ссылку на сервер с картинкой, то все равботе `var imgUrl = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAAA1BMVEV+Xl5R/nSpAAAAC0lEQVR4XmOgMgAAAFAAAWTxy78AAAAASUVORK5CYII=";`

Comment: еще я указал это : `data: {image: imgUrl, type: 'file'},`

Comment: @gilo1212, для `base64` нужно установить `type` как `base64`, см. документ.

Comment: Все равно не хочет работать - `data: {image: imgUrl, type: 'base64'},`

Comment: Может нужно передать как-нибудь имя файла?

Comment: Получилось, Спасибо, нужно было вот так `var imgUrl = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAAA1BMVEV+Xl5R/nSpAAAAC0lEQVR4XmOgMgAAAFAAAWTxy78AAAAASUVORK5CYII=';`

Comment: @gilo1212, рад что заработало :)